# Wrap elements within jQuery each loop within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

I've been working with getting some data parsed out from an XML feed to JSON and all of that works well. It's just that I'm trying to wrap each part of data within a `div`.

Here's the main part that I'm working with:

```
var newsDiv = $('<div class="news-feed">').appendTo($("body"));
    $(release).each(function(index, newsItem) {
      var idnum = newsItem.id;
      newsDiv.append($(document.createElement("h2")).text(newsItem.headline));
      newsDiv.append($(document.createElement("p")).text(newsItem.releaseDate));
      newsDiv.append('<a href="https://urltothing.com/'+idnum+'">Read More</a>'); 
    });
```

Which will output:

```
<h2>Headline</h2>
<p>Date things</p>
<a href="https://urltopage/123">Read More</a>
<h2>Headline2</h2>
<p>Date things2</p>
<a href="https://urltopage/456">Read More</a>
<h2>Headline3</h2>
<p>Date things3</p>
<a href="https://urltopage/789">Read More</a>
```

And so on. What I would like is to wrap all of those in a `<div>` so it looks like this:

```
<div>
<h2>Headline</h2>
<p>Date things</p>
<a href="https://urltopage/123">Read More</a>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Headline2</h2>
<p>Date things2</p>
<a href="https://urltopage/456">Read More</a>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Headline3</h2>
<p>Date things3</p>
<a href="https://urltopage/789">Read More</a>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to effectively go about doing that. Also, if there is anything else that could be done to clean up what I currently have, I'm all for that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the new empty div with `$('<div>')`, then call `.append` on it, passing 3 arguments (the 3 elements you're creating), and append it to the `newsDiv`:

```js
var newsDiv = $('<div class="news-feed">').appendTo($("body"));
const release = [{
  headline: 'headline',
  releaseDate: 'releaseDate',
  id: 1
}];
$(release).each(function(index, newsItem) {
  const $div = $('<div>').append(
    $('<h2>').text(newsItem.headline),
    $('<p>').text(newsItem.releaseDate),
    $('<a href="https://urltothing.com/' + newsItem.id + '">Read More</a>')
  );
  newsDiv.append($div);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It looks like you're mixing jQuery and vanilla DOM methods though, which is pretty weird. There's no need to require a big library like jQuery for something this trivial. If you want to use vanilla DOM methods, you could easily remove your dependency on jQuery if you wanted:

```js
var newsDiv = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
newsDiv.classList.add('news-feed');
const release = [{
  headline: 'headline',
  releaseDate: 'releaseDate',
  id: 1
}];
for (const { headline, releaseDate, id } of release) {
  const div = newsDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  div.innerHTML = '<h2></h2><p></p><a href="https://urltothing.com/' + id + '">Read More</a>';
  const [h2, p] = div.children;
  h2.textContent = headline;
  p.textContent = releaseDate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I'm working with a 3rd party data feed and trying to integrate that into a page on a larger CMS that I don't have access to the template files. So I'm trying to mash together something that will work and that I can wedge into a WYSIWYG editor. And the more that I look into it the more that the vanillaJS option might be better considering load times and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
var newsDiv = $('<div class="news-feed">').appendTo($("body"));
    $(release).each(function(index, newsItem) {
      var idnum = newsItem.id;
      newsDiv.wrap("<div>");
      newsDiv.append($(document.createElement("h2")).text(newsItem.headline));
      newsDiv.append($(document.createElement("p")).text(newsItem.releaseDate));
      newsDiv.append('<a href="https://urltothing.com/'+idnum+'">Read More</a>'); 
      newsDiv.wrap("</div>");
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to achieve this would be doing something like this:

```
var newsDiv = $('<div class="news-feed">').appendTo($("body"));
$(release).each(function(index, newsItem) {
  var itemDiv = $(document.createElement("div"));
  var idnum = newsItem.id;
  itemDiv.append($(document.createElement("h2")).text(newsItem.headline));
  itemDiv.append($(document.createElement("p")).text(newsItem.releaseDate));
  itemDiv.append('<a href="https://urltothing.com/'+idnum+'">Read More</a>'); 
  newsDiv.append(itemDiv);
});
```

Notice how I create another div element to wrap the other elements.

As for cleaning up the code, using a JS UI framework (like React [technically not a framework], Angular or Vue) would be the best way since it enforces certain practices on the developer and saves on the code necessary to perform common tasks.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if they have Vue.js loaded onto their CMS. Long story short...trying to get a feed from another vendor and parse that onto a page all within a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: @ultraloveninja I'm just offering a general solution to the problem, for the other people who may stumble upon this answer.

Answer (score -1):

please do the following:

```
var newsDiv = $('<div class="news-feed">').appendTo($("body"));
    $(release).each(function(index, newsItem) {
      var divi=document.createElement("div");
      var idnum = newsItem.id;
      divi.append($(document.createElement("h2")).text(newsItem.headline));
      divi.append($(document.createElement("p")).text(newsItem.releaseDate));
      divi.append('<a href="https://urltothing.com/'+idnum+'">Read More</a>'); 
      newsDiv.appendChild(divi);
    });
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.